# Google Play Store Upload Failed Without Info

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, google-play-services

After latest android studio and app signing updates, I can no longer upload an update APK  for my application. It does not even tell me why. Here is how it looks:
[image]

How can I find the problem?

Comment: Check the basics with the network on your end first to eliminate the obvious.

Comment: Network is fine.

Comment: try another browser, upload from another directory, from another drive, etc. I don;t think that we can tell you more than google play does (nothing) as we have no idea of what is wrong.

Comment: Also check the browser's developer console for error messages

Comment: Are you sure its not related to app signining considering the latest updates?

Comment: {"errorMessage":{"reason":"REQUEST_REJECTED","additionalInfo":{"uploader_service.GoogleRupioAdditionalInfo":{"completionInfo":{"status":"REJECTED","customerSpecificInfo":{"processed_upload_response":"{\"6\":2}"}},"requestRejectedInfo":{"reasonDescription":"agent_rejected"}}},"upload_id":"xxxxx"}}

Comment: This is the response of my upload request.

Comment: try changing minor version number and upload to see it removes error?

Comment: same thing happened to me today. I tried in opera and chrome. They gave same error.with no info. Please post here if you can figure it out.